# how to pivot result based upon physical column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

[image: pivot result based upon physical table's column]

I have three tables 
1. Master table M_MasterTable
2. Detail Table of M_MasterTable
3. Actual Physical Table

How to write a query that will give me desire output, by matching physical columns with fieldname(2) to get in pivoting result?

Id is primary key
detailed is foreign key.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwXKH.png): [image]

Comment: Please include the examples in the question as text / code, not pictures -- and also what you have done so far

Comment: How do the first 2 tables link together? Seems like you need some dynamic SQL in order to read the tables and write a query in order to alias the columns.

Comment: you need a foreign key coumn "tableid" in your details table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
--Quick and Dirty Sample Data
DECLARE @master TABLE
(
    id INT,
    tablename NVARCHAR(100) 
)

DECLARE @detail TABLE
(
    detailid INT,
    tableid INT,
    fieldname NVARCHAR(100),
    excelmappingcolumn NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @master VALUES (1,N'A')

INSERT INTO @detail VALUES (1,1,N'Code',N'VirtualCode')
INSERT INTO @detail VALUES (2,1,N'Value',N'Value of Virtual Exam')


-- Getting the query
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[','',@columns + ',[') + fieldname + '] AS [' + excelmappingcolumn + ']'
FROM    @detail WHERE tableid = 1    

SELECT @stmt = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + tablename
FROM    @master m
WHERE m.id = 1

PRINT @stmt

--Execute 
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```